# How to list out two different product's details at the same table with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I only can list out all the data row by row but I want to list out those 2 products  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0cGG.png) from top to bottom, not [row by row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkJOW.png) within

[index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwQWT.png)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<td><'.$row['name'].'></td>';
}
```

[server.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUDZJ.png)

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','crud');

$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info");
```

Comment: So you want to print out a column for each product? Iterate through the items?

Comment: @shn You changed the question with your edit. You should not do that.

Comment: @shn yes, i want to compare two products within entering the name at the textbox but it shown like that > row by row

Comment: So each product will have its own column?

Comment: @shn yup, each product have its own column

Comment: @KelvinTan You should post bigger chunk of your code, so we can see how you create the table instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

If I really understand, you want each product to be in a different line. If yes, you could create new rows directly inside your loop like this

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
       echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';
    }
```

Comment: Thank, but i want to list out the product from top to bottom that have its own column to show

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    $detail_row.="<td>" . $row['items'] . "</td>";
    $category_row.="<td>" . $row['items'] . "</td>";
}

?>
<table> 
  <tr>
    <td>Details</td>
    <?php echo $detail_row; ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Categories</td>
    <?php echo $category_row; ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```